# Importing cython generated *.so-module with another python-version or on another OS

Tags: python, shared-libraries, cython

How should a file `myModule.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so` be imported in python? Is it possible?

I tried the regular way:

```
import myModule
```

and the interpreter says:

```
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myModule'`
```

This is a software that I can't install in the cluster that I am working at so I just extracted the `.deb` package and it does not have a wheel file or structure to install.

Comment: my guess is, that you aren't using Python3.5 for which the extension was built. There must be a duplicate somewhere...

Comment: @ead You are right. Now I am in the next bug... :(  Nevertheless, If you have the confidence that these `*so` files are imported as regular except that the version that is part of the filename should be use, please, feel free to formulate an answer that will also help others with similar questions! BTW, it would be a plus (and helpful to me right now) if you know where should other c shared libraries be related to the *so (if there is a default?). Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is problematic to use a C-extension built for one Python version in another Python version. Normally (at least for Python3) there is a mechanism in place to differentiate C-extensions for different Python versions, so they can co-exist in the same directory.

In your example, the suffix is `cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu` so this C-extension will be picked up by a CPython3.5 on a x86_64 Linux. If you try to import this extension with another Python-version or on another plattform, the module isn't visible and `ModuleNotFoundError` is raised.

It is possible to see, which suffixes are accepted by the current Python version, e.g. via:

```
>>> import _imp
>>>_imp.extension_suffixes()
['.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so', '.abi3.so', '.so']
```

A possibility is to use the stable C-API which could be used with multiple Python versions without recompilation. Cython start to support it in version 3.0 (see [this PR](https://github.com/cython/cython/pull/3223)), see also this [SO-post](https://github.com/cython/cython/pull/3223) about `setuptools` and stable C-API.

One might want to be clever and rename the extension to simple `.so`, so it can be picked up by the Finder - this can/does work for some Python-version combinations on some platforms for some extension - yet this approach cannot be sustained in the long run and is **not** the right thing to do.

**The right thing to do, is to build the C-extension for/with the right Python-version on the right OS/platform or to use the right wheel (or use stable C-API).**

---

In general, a C-extension built for a python-version (let's say PythonA.B) cannot be used by another Python version (let's say PythonC.D), because those extensions/modules are linked against a special Python-library and the needed functionality might no longer/not yet be present in the library of another version.

This different to `*.py`-files and more similar to `*.pyc`-files which cannot be used with a different version.

While [PEP-3147](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3147/) regulates the suffices of `*.pyc`-files, [PEP-3149](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3149/) does the same for the C-extensions. [PEP-3149](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3149/) is however not the state-of-the-art, as some of the problems where fixed only [in Python3.5](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Doc/whatsnew/3.5.rst#build-and-c-api-changes), the whole discussion can be found [here](https://bugs.python.org/issue22980).