# How to make a cython library available to my python program?

Tags: python, cython

I am working on a legacy project which uses a cython library:

```
engine.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```

It is downloaded to my current working directory:

```
engine.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
test.py
```

Then in the test.py, it tried to import from engine library:

```
from engine import authenticate
```

Currently, it cant't find the engine library. Suppose my current virtual environment is 'test', how can I make the 'engine' library to my virtual environment 'test'?

The original project uses a docker deployment and i want to get rid of the docker environment and test it in a pure pip environment.

Comment: What do you mean by "it is downloaded to my current working directory"?  Where did you download it from?  Are you running the exact same Python version and architecture, etc. ?  It may be you have to build it yourself.

Comment: can you try explicitly adding current directory to PYTHONPATH when running `test.py`? like this: `PYTHONPATH=. python test.py`

Comment: Probably duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/65597206/5769463

Comment: @Marat No. It doesn't work.

Comment: I just tested it and it worked fine on Linux but can't work on Mac. How can I get a Mac version of the 'engine.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'?

Comment: @marlon You would need the source code of that legacy project, in order to compile/build it in your MacOS system.